# DTOR not called when using shared_ptr

Tags: c++

I'm running into some really strange behavior. One of my classes (Class `A`) holds a shared_ptr to a class `Connector`. Other classes also hold shared_ptr to that `Connector` instance. I noticed that the `Connector`'s destructor doesn't get called after everything goes out of scope. However, if I hold the `Connector` in class `A` as a reference instead of a shared_ptr, the destructor is called and everything works out.

Sorry for not sharing any code, but it's part of a big codebase and I'm having trouble extracting smaller, relevant bits.

So my question is: do you have any idea why switching from a shared_ptr to a reference member could influence the behavior in that way? Maybe it has to do with some cyclic DTOR calls due to the various shared_ptr?

I appreciate any hints you might have!

P.S: All base classes have virtual DTORs. That's one of the first things I checked..

Comment: Please share a [mre] instead of describing the code. Making a small example shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: Definitely cyclic ownership. Typically `A -> B -> C -> A` (because if it was obvious, you'd see right away)/.

Comment: this is called strong reference cycle. Basically your code design is flawed (in good code such cycle of dependencies should not exists). One what to fix is is to use `std::weak_ptr`, but remeber somthing else have to hold strong reference to same object as `weak_ptr` to sustain lifetime of object.

Comment: When using smart pointers you should check if you really express ownership at these points. There are for sure situations where you could argue that for a circular dependency everything expresses ownership, and in those cases, you might want to break this strong relationship with a `weak_ptr` at the appropriate point. In many cases, a non-owning raw pointer (or a reference) could be used instead (e.g. for tree-like structures where you want to reference parents, siblings, … for which those relations don't express ownership)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens when you have a cycle. That means objects point to each other in a cycle, so the reference count never goes to zero. You have to fix the cycle. C++ specifically has a [`weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) type to use in such situations, which could be useful in your case as well.

> However, if I hold the Connector in class A as a reference instead of a `shared_ptr`, the destructor is called and everything works out.

This possibly means that the ownership is not well thought through and `A` should not be an owner. People often default to `shared_ptr` because it seems easier to use but, in fact, it complicates the ownership system. In many cases, you could have a single owner object, holding a `unique_ptr`, and everyone else could refer to the object without owning it. This could be done with non-owning raw pointers, etc.

Comment: Thank you (and everyone else as well) for your helpful comment! It was indeed a cyclic dependency. I drew a graph to figure it out the loops and managed to fix the problem.